# Can Net::LDAP and Parallel::Forkmanager work together?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, ldap

I need to query different LDAP servers in perl via [Net::LDAP](http://search.cpan.org/~marschap/perl-ldap-0.64/lib/Net/LDAP.pod). I have something that works well. However, in an attempt to speed up things, I tried to query the different servers in parallel, using [Parallel::Forkmanager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm) - and things do not work when I do that.

I get the following types of errors:

```
 decode error 02<=>30 0 8  at /Users/myname/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/Convert/ASN1/_decode.pm line 113, <> line 18.
 decode error 43<=>30 0 8  at /Users/myname/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/Convert/ASN1/_decode.pm line 113, <> line 25.
```

at the line that gets the search response:

```
$mesg = $ldap->search( base => $dn, filter => '(CN=*)');
```

I am puzzled.

Telling it in other other words, why does this fail:

```
use Net::LDAP;
use Parallel::Forkmanager;

...; # bind LDAP servers

while (<>) {
    chop;
    my $dn = $_;
    foreach my $ldap (@servers) {
        my $pid;
        $pid = $pm->start and next; # do the fork
        print $dn, $pid;
        my $mesg;
        try {
            $mesg = $ldap->search( base => $dn, filter => '(CN=*)');
        } catch {
            ...;
        }
        $pm->finish;
    }
}
```

while this:

```
use Net::LDAP;

...; # bind LDAP servers

while (<>) {
    chop;
    my $dn = $_;
    foreach my $ldap (@servers) {
        print $dn;
        my $mesg;
        try {
            $mesg = $ldap->search( base => $dn, filter => '(CN=*)');
        } catch {
            ...;
        }
    }
}
```

works perfectly?

Comment: Is `@servers` a list of `Net::LDAP` objects? It looks like it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst `fork`ing doesn't have quite the same thread safety problems of `thread`ing - there are still a few places you have gotchas. I think this is what's biting you - your `Net::LDAP` objects are created in the parent thread, but then (effectively) cloned to each when you fork.

Which means in *your* code - there's a very real possibility that if you've got the list of names coming in fast enough, that a new fork will try to reuse an existing Net::LDAP connection before a previous one is finished with it.

The easy way of preventing this is call `wait_all_children` to ensure all your parallel LDAP queries are finished before the next one starts.

If you put your LDAP bind within the `ForkManager` loop, do you still have the same problem? I appreciate that's a potential overhead as you'll be binding each iteration, but if that addresses it, I'd suggest that it's because `Net::LDAP` is sharing the same file descriptors between forks.

The next best solution there would be to adopt a 'worker' model, where you've got a bunch of 'workers' each with their on LDAP connections to do the querying. That's easier with threading, than `fork`ing - goes a bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

sub server_worker {
    my ( $hostname, $q_ref ) = @_;

    ## connect LDAP to $hostname;
    while ( my $dn = $$q_ref->dequeue ) {

        #query $dn
    }
}

my @queues;

foreach my $server (@list_of_servers) {
    my $server_q = Threads::Queue->new();
    push( @queues, $server_q );
    threads->create( \&server_worker, $hostname, \$server_q );
}

while ( my $dn = <STDIN> ) {
    chomp($dn);
    foreach my $q (@queues) {
        $q->enqueue($dn);
    }
}

foreach my $q ( @queues ) { 
    $q -> end;
}

foreach my $thr ( threads->list ) {
    $thr->join();
}
```

Doing something similar with forking should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Pipe;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Net::LDAP;

my @list_of_servers = qw ( servername servenama anotherserver );

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager -> new ( scalar @list_of_servers );

my %pipe_for;

foreach my $server ( @list_of_servers ) {
   my $pipe = IO::Pipe -> new();
   my $pid = pm -> start;
   if ( $pid ) {
       print "$$: parent\n";
       $pipe -> writer -> autoflush;
       $pipe_for{$server} = $pipe;
   }
   else {
       print "$$ child connecting to $server\n"; 
       $pipe -> reader -> autoflush;
       close ( STDIN ); #because this is a child. 
        #Net::LDAP setup
       while ( my $item =  <$pipe> ) {
           chomp ( $item );
            #ldap_search $item;
       }
    }
   $pm -> finish; 
}
```

And then send stuff:

```
for my $number ( 1..10 ) { 
   foreach my $pipe ( values %pipe_for ) { 
       print {$pipe} "test$number\n";
   }
}

$pm -> wait_all_children();
```

Edit: Note - autoflush is important, otherwise the IO buffers and doesn't look like it's working. I'm pretty sure closing STDIN is probably a good idea in the child, but perhaps not vitally necessary if they don't use it.